# how to disable Javascript debugging in production

Tags: javascript, debugging, browser

I want to disable debugging of my javascript code in production. Is there any way i can do it by injecting any script in my code, so that any one cannot debugger the code in there browsers?

Comment: Doesn't sound possible at all as you have already given away your code.

Comment: What do you mean disable debugging? Disable logging messages or disable the js console. It is not possible to disable the js console. Even if a browser disables it it doesn't stop someone from creating another browser to enable it. Most browsers are open source after all and some of them have fairly clean, easy to read source code.

Comment: If you don't want that the user can debug your script, don't send it to him so that he cannot run it.

Comment: i was just thinking if we can do that. but as @pang said, it not possible i guess. thanks for the answers!